# Assembler. Запихивание несколько значений в один байт

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте!
Как я узнал, mov копирует **байт** (можно и word, dword, но не меньше) из "источника" в "приёмник".
И у меня возник вопрос: а можно ли "запихнуть" в один байт по какому - то адресу несколько значений, общий вес которых меньше него?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "вес"? Один байт можно интерпретировать как 8 однобитовых значений, между прочим.

Comment: Наименьшая единица "значения" - это бит. В байте помещается 8 бит. Каждый бит может иметь два состояния. Так что да, можно.

Comment: В моём понимание "вес" - размер в битах.

Comment: Значит можно через битовые операции.

Comment: Можно пользоваться этим для записи. Но при чтении придётся пользоваться сдвигами.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, напиши ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Огромное спасибо Владимиру Мартьянову. 
Можно использовать **[данный способ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5#.D0.9E.D0.B1_.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F.D1.85)**. То есть использовать битовые операции (or, xor, and) вместе с операциями сдвига. Это замедлит доступ к определённым битам, но позволит эффективно паковать их.